# How to return 1 columns value from a matrix on R?

Tags: r, if-statement, matrix, vector

I am trying to match values from one vector (1,7) to a matrix (2,21)

The goal here is to match the vector values to the matrix values as there are equal values within both, shown in example e.g.

```
if(Removed[,1] %like% T1PickProb[2]){
  print("yes")
} else{
  print("no match")
}

T1PickProb
[output]
0.01754386 0.06140351 0.13157895 0.23684211 0.28070175 0.17543860 0.09649123

Removed
[output]
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]       [,6]       [,7]       [,8]       [,9]      [,10]      [,11]     [,12]     [,13]     [,14]      [,15]     [,16]     [,17]      [,18]
[1,] 0.01754386 0.01754386 0.01754386 0.01754386 0.01754386 0.01754386 0.06140351 0.06140351 0.06140351 0.06140351 0.06140351 0.1315789 0.1315789 0.1315789 0.13157895 0.2368421 0.2368421 0.23684211
[2,] 0.06140351 0.13157895 0.23684211 0.28070175 0.17543860 0.09649123 0.13157895 0.23684211 0.28070175 0.17543860 0.09649123 0.2368421 0.2807018 0.1754386 0.09649123 0.2807018 0.1754386 0.09649123
         [,19]      [,20]      [,21]
[1,] 0.2807018 0.28070175 0.17543860
[2,] 0.1754386 0.09649123 0.09649123
```

This should print out "yes" as T1PickProb[2] is 0.06140351 which is in Removed[,1] which has two values 0.01754386 & 0.06140351. However it prints out "no match"

So my question is, is there a way I can match values to specific columns within the matrix?
I have tried the following

```
Removed[,1]
```

but this returns the following error when running the about if statement:

```
In if (Removed[, 1] %like% T1PickProb[2]) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I have also tried

```
Removed[1,2]
```

However this return the first value in the second column. What else can I do?

Comment: `if` isn't vectorised. Try `any` or `ifelse` for a vectorised `if`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to illustrate:

```
if(any(removed[,1] %in% T1PickProb[2])){
  print("yes")
} else{
  print("no match")
}

> "yes"
```

That is because

```
> removed[,1] %in% T1PickProb[2]
[1] FALSE  TRUE
```

yields a vector with two elements. To see if any of these two is true, you can use `any`:

```
> any(removed[,1] %in% T1PickProb[2])
[1] TRUE
```

You can also vectorise this further, e.g.

Using the fact that:

```
removed %in% T1PickProb
 [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[21]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[41]  TRUE  TRUE
```

you could do

```
ifelse(removed %in% T1PickProb, "yes", "no match")
 [1] "yes"      "yes"      "yes"      "yes"      "yes"      "yes"      "yes"      "yes"      "yes"      "yes"      "yes"     
[12] "yes"      "yes"      "yes"      "yes"      "yes"      "yes"      "yes"      "yes"      "yes"      "yes"      "yes"     
[23] "no match" "no match" "no match" "no match" "no match" "yes"      "yes"      "yes"      "no match" "no match" "no match"
[34] "yes"      "yes"      "yes"      "no match" "yes"      "yes"      "yes"      "yes"      "yes"
```

Answer (score 0):

This function returns a list of the columns each value of `T1PickProb` is found using Base-R

```
lapply(T1PickProb, function(y) which( apply(removed, 2, function(x) any(x %in% y)) ==1))

[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6

[[2]]
[1]  1  7  8  9 10 11

[[3]]
[1]  2  7 15

[[4]]
[1]  3  8 18

[[5]]
[1]  4  9 20

[[6]]
[1]  5 10 14 17 19 21

[[7]]
[1]  6 11 15 18 20 21
```

Data:

```
removed <- structure(c(0.01754386, 0.06140351, 0.01754386, 0.13157895, 0.01754386, 
0.23684211, 0.01754386, 0.28070175, 0.01754386, 0.1754386, 0.01754386, 
0.09649123, 0.06140351, 0.13157895, 0.06140351, 0.23684211, 0.06140351, 
0.28070175, 0.06140351, 0.1754386, 0.06140351, 0.09649123, 0.1315789, 
0.2368421, 0.1315789, 0.2807018, 0.1315789, 0.1754386, 0.13157895, 
0.09649123, 0.2368421, 0.2807018, 0.2368421, 0.1754386, 0.23684211, 
0.09649123, 0.2807018, 0.1754386, 0.28070175, 0.09649123, 0.1754386, 
0.09649123), .Dim = c(2L, 21L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, NULL))

T1PickProb <- c(0.01754386,0.06140351,0.13157895,0.23684211,0.28070175,0.17543860,0.09649123)
```